# How to upload recorded audio blob to server without method='post' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to create a voice recorder in flask that takes the voice recording and then further processes the audio file.

For the voice recorder I am using the recorder code in this github repo: https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo

After the voice is recorder, I want to save it to disk and then process it using another python library

Here is the layout of my website:

[image]

I want the user to record their audio, and when stop button is pressed the audio should save to disk. then when `submit` is pressed, I want the python code to get the audio and process it.

To make this work, I changed the code from the above linked github to the following:

```
function stopRecording() {
    console.log("stopButton clicked");

    //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = true;

    //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
    pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    //tell the recorder to stop the recording
    rec.stop();

    //stop microphone access
    gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

    rec.exportWAV(saveAudioFile);
}

function saveAudioFile(blob) {
    // the file name is taken from python code.. for some reason this one is not considered
    var filename = new Date().toISOString();

    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState === 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          xhr.open("POST","/",true);
          xhr.send(fd);

}
```

When the `stop` button is pressed it calls the `saveAudioFile` function that saves the audio file to disk.

Here is my html code:

```
<h2>Step 1: Record your voice</h2>
      <br>
      <div align="center" id="controls">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="recordButton">Start Recording</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="stopButton">Stop Recording</button>
     </div>
     <div align="center" id="formats">Format: start recording to see sample rate</div>
     <br>

     <h2>Step 2: Select your target language</h2>
     <br>
      <form class="languageSelect" align="center" method="POST">
        <select class="form-select" name="languageSelector" id="languageSelector" aria-label="Select your target language">
            <option selected>Select target language</option>
            <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
            <option value="zh-Hans">Chinese Simplified</option>
            <option value="de">German (Germany)</option>
            <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
            <option value="fr">French</option>
            <option value="it">Italian</option>
          </select>

          <br>
          <br>

          <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit2" onclick="loading()" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="display:none;"></i>
           <span class="btn-text">Submit</span>
   </button>
      </form>
      <br>

    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
    <script src="/static/js/recorder.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- below script will show the loading animation on button click..-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loading() {
    $(".btn .fa-circle-o-notch").show();
    $(".btn .btn-text").html("Please Wait...");
  
    }
  
    </script>
```

This works and creates the audio file, but the problem is that it does so with `method='POST'`.

So when the stop button is clicked to stop the recording, the `flask` code for `method=='POST'` also gets executed and that causes problems as the language selector is empty and the submit button is not pressed.

Here is the flask code for this page:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        lang = request.form.getlist("languageSelector")
        print("Language Selected: " + str(lang))
        filename = 'audio.wav'
        filepath = os.path.join('audio-files', filename)
        print(request.files)
        f = request.files['audio_data']
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as audio:
            f.save(audio)
        print('file uploaded successfully')
        translted_text = translate_audio_to_text(filepath, lang)
        synthesize_audio(translted_text)

        return render_template('home.html', request="POST")                     
        
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
```

As can be seen, when the stop button is pressed in the recorder, it also executes all the code in the `if request.method == "POST":` block which causes the app to fail.

I'm very new to javascript so am struggling with this. Is there a way to save the audio file without `POST` method?

Comment: To send a bunch of stuff from browser to server, POST is the proper way to do it. It's not clear why your "Stop" button *also* posts the form. If you post your HTML that might become clear.

Comment: @Pointy Ive updated my question and added the html code. Also, the stop button calling the post form method is my change to the javascript code from the github repo. The original code would show the recording and then user would have to click ``Upload``. But I wanted the sound to be available for processing, so I added ``rec.exportWAV(saveAudioFile);`` in the ``onclick``of the stop button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then when `submit` is pressed, I want the python code to get the audio and process it.

In that case you're sending your audio file too early to the server. You are currently sending it when *Stop Recording* is pressed. You should add the file to the form instead, then let the form submit the file as part of its default action.

To do this add a `<input type="file">` to your `<form>`.

```html
<input required
  id="audio_data"
  name="audio_data"
  type="file"
  accept="audio/wav"
/>
```

Then, when *Stop Recording* is pressed, update the file list of the input.

```js
function saveAudioFile(blob) {
    // the file name is taken from python code.. for some reason this one is not considered
    const filename = new Date().toISOString();
    const file = new File([blob], filename, { type: blob.type });

    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.items.add(file);

    const audioDataInput = document.getElementById("audio_data");
    audioDataInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
    // [optional] fire a change event for attached handlers
    // audioDataInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
}
```

This should update the `<input type="file">` attached file to the audio that was just recorded. It also allows users to choose a file from their computer instead. If you don't want this element visible, you can hide it through CSS or the `style` attribute.

The attached file is now submitted whenever the user submits the form (aka presses *submit*).

---

Alternatively, you could omit the `<input type="file">` and store the data in a variable instead. Then attach to `FormData` after `<form>` constructs it.

```
let savedAudio;
function saveAudioFile(blob) {
    // the file name is taken from python code.. for some reason this one is not considered
    savedAudio = blob;
}

document.forms["your-form-id"].addEventListener("formdata", (e) => {
    const filename = new Date().toISOString();
    e.formData.set("audio_data", blob, filename);
});
```

The main difference is the **the former solution allows you to make the input required** without the use of JavaScript. By simply having `<input required type="file">` the browser doesn't allow a submit.

Since this alternative doesn't have a required input a submit is allowed and you might need to add custom validation before the form is submitted.

```js
document.forms["your-form-id"].addEventListener("formdata", (e) => {
    const filename = new Date().toISOString();
    if (blob) e.formData.set("audio_data", blob, filename);
});

document.forms["your-form-id"].addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if (e.formData.has("audio_data")) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    // inform user of missing audio data
});
```

For details on this second answer see the [`formdata` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/formdata_event) (and [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful. I used your first proposed solution of ``<input type="file">`` and since I did not want the upload button, I used ``style="display: none"`` to hide it as suggested by you.